# Stripe Account Transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am working on transfer amount from one account to another account using stripe.I have enough amount in my test mode but i am getting the insufficient fund error.I am working on since 15 days but i am not able to find any feasible solution for that.
The code which i am using for transfer the amount is as:

```
@pay = 
  Stripe::Transfer.create({
    amount: @offer_transaction.amount.to_i, 
    currency: 'hkd', 
    destination: @offer_transaction.transfer_payment_in,
    description: 'Transfer for test@example.com'
  },
  {
    :stripe_account => @user.stripe_connect_account_id
  })
```

Comment: Whats the value for `@offer_transaction.amount.to_i`..?

Comment: @offer_transaction.amount.to_i   is 10000

Comment: Whats the card number or account that you are using..?

Comment: I am using stripe account and using stripe account id for that

Comment: You have mentioned that its a test account. So if you are using account number 000222222227 then the transfers will return the insufficient fund error. If you have used the above account number then try to use the valid accounts using the https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Comment: having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Each Stripe account has two different types of balances: [`available`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_object-available) (meaning funds are available to be transferred out to an external bank account) and [`pending`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_object-pending) (meaning funds are not yet available).

When you create a charge and new funds are added, they're initially added to the pending balance, and only become available after a delay.

You can check an account's balance with the ["retrieve balance"](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance) API call. In test mode, you can also create charges with this card number: [`4000 0000 0000 0077`](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) and the funds from the charge will be immediately available.

Comment: "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {"currency":"usd","amount":617190,"source_types":{"card":617190,"bank_account":0}}
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {"currency":"usd","amount":8103,"source_types":{"card":8103,"bank_account":0}}
  ]
}